# Covert NVARCHAR to number (digits after decimal sign vary)

Tags: sql, oracle, decimal

Do you know how I can convert NVARCHAR in Oracle if the digits after decimal signs vary?

I need this in order to convert it to date, using this formula:

```
select to_date('12/30/1899', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + 40676.2641666667
from dual;
```

The thing is that the digits in the second part (40676.2641666667) vary so I can use to_number(t.column, '99999D9999999999'), because it doesn't work this way.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Does that code fail?

Comment: No, It works but my column is in NVARCHAR and when I try to use it, it fails.

I need to change the code to 
select to_date('12/30/1899', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + t.column

Answer (score 0):

These all work for me:

```
select (date '1899-12-30') + '40676.2641666667'
from dual
```

and:

```
select (date '1899-12-30') + cast('40676.2641666667' as number)
from dual
```

and:

```
select (date '1899-12-30') + 40676.2641666667
from dual
```

One caveat is that internationalization settings might require comma instead of period.

Comment: Hi! It works if I use a single record - 40676.2641666667 or 40676.26416555555 or 40676.346333, but I can't use the how column. I tried with cast(t.column as number), but it doesn't work.

Comment: @SammyMerk . . . Any of these should work with a column name as well as a constant.  However, it is only possible to answer the question that you asked, and this question is about a constant value.  I would suggest that you ask another question, providing sample data, the table definition, and your internationalization settings.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't have NVARCHAR, it has NVARCHAR2.  The following works for me:

```
DECLARE
    nv_Number       NVARCHAR2(0032) := 40676.2641666667;
    dt_Base     DATE           := TO_DATE('12/30/1899', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
    dt_Result       DATE;
BEGIN
    dt_Result := dt_Base + TO_NUMBER(nv_Number);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(dt_Result,'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss'));
END;
```

Result: 20110513 06:20:24